# Trying to use Python + XPath to click the highlighted text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Fairly new to coding and Python, I'm trying to use `find_element_by_xpath` to click the text highlighted text `"Snoring Chin Strap by TheFamilyMarket"`.

```
    time.sleep(2)

    #btn = br.find_element_by_name("#Anti Snoring Chin Strap Kit")
    # btn = br.find_element_by_link_text('Snoring Chin Strap')
```

The HTML code:

```html
<div class="tableD">
   <div class="productDiv" id="productDiv69507">
      <h2 class="productTitle" id="productTitle69507" onclick="goToProduct(7)">Snoring Chin Strap by TheFamilyMarket</h2>
      <img class="productImage" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/516fC3JruqL.jpg" onclick="goToProduct(7)">
      <hr>
      <h4 class="normalPrice" id="normalPrice7" onclick="goToProduct(7)">Normally: <span class="currency">$  </span>19.99</h4>
      <h4 class="promoPrice" style="margin:2.5px auto;" id="promoPrice69507" onclick="goToProduct(7)">Your Amazon Price: <span class="currency">$  </span>1.99</h4>
      <h3>Your Total:  <span class="currency">$  </span>1.99</h3>
      <p class="clickToViewP" id="cToVP69507" onclick="goToProduct(7)">Click to view and purchase!</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your code, and the relevant portion of your target page as text in the body of your question.

Comment: I added the code and the other image can be found here https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOLHX.png

Comment: @Kas,  Show HTML code in screenshot is a bad practice, Please add them in your question as text content.

Answer (score 1):

```
br.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[text()='Snoring Chin Strap by TheFamilyMarket']");
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! Also, got your comment about the bad practice and will definitely make sure my next post meets proper standards.

Answer (score 0):

XPath is sometimes fast to get because you can get it from the browser, and that's why so many people use it, but in my opinion for long term, learning JavaScript and CSS selectors can help you in many instances in the future.
The above can be done also by selecting all the `h2` elements and looking for text using plain JavaScript and passing the result to python:

```
link_you_search = br.execute_script('''
links= document.querySelectorAll("h2");
for (link of links) if (link.textContent.includes("Chin Strap")) return link;
 ''')
link_you_search.click()
```

or alternatively you can select by class:

```
link_you_search = br.execute_script('''
links= document.querySelectorAll(".productDiv");
for (link of links) if (link.textContent.includes("Chin Strap")) return link;
 ''')
link_you_search.click()
```

given that your element has an `id` attribute usually selecting by `id` it is best practice since it is the fastest search and you should only have only one element with that `id` and usually `id`s don't change so often in case of translation etc, so in your case it would be:

```
link_you_search = br.find_element_by_id('productTitle69507')
link_you_search.click()
```